# Archive slider for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, archive-template

I have a custom post type and archive page. I want to be able to use the default twentyfourteen theme slider so that the archive-cpt.php page calls the js and displays a slider only for the CPT. I imagine I call a function, but I don't know how to write the script or how to call it from. I know the js location of the slider. Any help here would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The slider script is called with the following lines of code

```
if ( is_front_page() && 'slider' == get_theme_mod( 'featured_content_layout' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20131205', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'twentyfourteen-slider', 'featuredSliderDefaults', array(
        'prevText' => __( 'Previous', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'nextText' => __( 'Next', 'twentyfourteen' )
    ) );
}
```

You just need to copy these lines and add them in your child theme and change your condition accordingly. The following in your child theme should work. Note: I believe here that you leave the js files in the parent theme

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_slider_scripts', 11 );
function enqueue_slider_scripts()
{
    if (     is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' ) // Change 'cpt' your match your exact cpt 
         && 'slider' == get_theme_mod( 'featured_content_layout' ) 
    ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20131205', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'twentyfourteen-slider', 'featuredSliderDefaults', array(
            'prevText' => __( 'Previous', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'nextText' => __( 'Next', 'twentyfourteen' )
        ) );
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Just remember to copy the following lines to your archive page to display your slider

```
<?php                
    if ( twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() )               
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );        
?>
```

Comment: Cheers Pieter, I assume this code goes into the function.php file?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct for the first section. The second block of code goes into your archive page

Comment: I did what you tried, and instead of starting the slider it posts what would be the slider, it piled posts on top of each other, and didn't call from the CPT posts. Instead, it called from the main blogroll.

Comment: If you need posts only from the specific post type, you will need to customize the slider.

Comment: As in, the js of the slider?

Comment: OK, I was playing with some of the code from [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-custom-post-types-to-featured-post-area). It appears to call the CPT, but then the slider interface does not load as it should. Is this where we need to customise the js slider? @Pieter

Comment: I cannot see why this does not work. Does the js load, did you check and make sure in browser console. Did you change `cpt` in line `is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' )` to your exact custom post type name